# Replacing multiple lines in text files using python

Tags: python, string, replace

I know how to replace a string in python, but I am struggling to get this to work, perhaps because this is a block of text instead of a single line that I want to replace.

I have a bunch of text files which have the following block of text repeated in them at multiple places :

> ```
>                    LIVEBLAH Information Provided By:
>                               BLAH ONLINE
>           A division of Blahdeblah BlahBlah Information, Inc.
>
> Washington, DC                    New York, NY                  Chicago, IL
> Los Angeles, CA                     Miami, FL                    Dallas, TX
>
>           For Additional Information About LIVEBLAH, Call
>                            1-800-XXX-XXXX
>                  or Visit Us on the World Wide Web at
>                        http://www.blahdeblah.com
> ```

I want to replace every occurrence of this block of text with the string "start body"

This is the code I'm trying :

```
import os,glob
path = 'files'
key="""
                      LIVEBLAH Information Provided By:
                                   BLAH ONLINE
               A division of Blahdeblah BlahBlah Information, Inc.

Washington, DC                    New York, NY                  Chicago, IL
Los Angeles, CA                     Miami, FL                    Dallas, TX

                For Additional Information About LIVEBLAH, Call
                                1-800-XXX-XXXX
                      or Visit Us on the World Wide Web at
                            http://www.blahdeblah.com"""

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        # read entire file into file1
        file1 = f.read()

        # replace block of text with proper string
        file1 = file1.replace(key, "start body")

        # write into a new file
        with open(filename+'_new', 'w') as f:
            f.write(file1)
```

Can someone tell me why the replace() method isn't working with a block of text? What can I do to make it work?

EDIT --
I tried a different methodology :

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt_new_NEW_NEW_BLAH')):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        # read entire file into file1
        file1 = f.read()

        # index() will raise an error if not found
        f1_start = file1.index('LIVEBLAH Information Provided By:')
        f1_end = file1.index('http://www.blahdeblah.com', f1_start)     

        key = file1[f1_start:(f1_end+25)] # 25 is the length of the string 'http://www.blahdeblah.com' 
        file1 = file1.replace(key, '\n'+"start body")

        with open(filename+'_TRIAL', 'w') as f:
            f.write(file1)
```

This gives a strange result - for some of the files it works perfectly. For others it only replaces the string 'LIVEBLAH Information Provided By:' with 'start body', but leaves the rest of the text block as it is. For some others index() raises an error saying it can't find the string 'LIVEBLAH Information Provided By:' in the file, even though it is clearly there.
What is going on?

Comment: are you sure the replace isn't working? I notice that when you write the new text, you write to a file with no .txt extension

Comment: Yes, that is just to check the output of the code. Would it make a difference if I write it to a .txt file?

Answer (score 0):

Since tabs and newlines will be encoded as '\t' and '\n' or '\r' (depending on the OS or file editor used to create the file) respectively so I'll suggest you to get a unicode dump of the text file and use that string in the replace command. Otherwise you might be interpreting tab as multiple spaces and so on.

Comment: That seems like a possible solution! How can I get a unicode dump of text files?

Comment: That you are doing already in second step while using file1.read() just split it to get the header that's already there and then use replace()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try something like that, but I'm getting strange results. I edited my original question - could you have a look and see if that's the same methodology you are recommending?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suggested... Try to output key to check if things are happening the way they should